# How can we add a floating toolbar by vba for ppt?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a floating vertical toolbar (like picture below) on the left side of the slide pane in PPT. want this pane to have 10 rows of color pickers with all the 10 accent (template) colors from the current template and 3 columns with one each for Font color, Fill color and Line color. Can anybody direct me with suitable resource or starting point to have the toolbar setup with the accent colors loaded on it. I can build on to it.

[image]

Comment: You might be able to use a modeless userform in VBA for this. Floating toolbars are obsolete in Office, the current practice is to modify the Ribbon. If you can manage the learning curve, you can also create custom task panes using VSTO or Office.js.

Comment: Thanks for the update John. if we use modeless userform, how can we stick it inside the PPT workarea like this toolbox/toolbar as shown above

Comment: You would use the _Show_ method to display the userform: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method